# How to post arguments to resolve security image problem

Tags: java

I am writing java code where i need to get some information from a particular website. i am writing java code that uses scrapping method , but while scraping data from website i am facing one problem.

When i go through the links one page to another page some time it shows security image page. I get the security string by using an API,but when i m trying to post it using postmethod in java. I can't able to get actual page source, it redirects the same security image page. How to solve this problem. How can I post arguments to resolve security image problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the security image implementor's point of view, this is usually implemented by saving your session id with the security string, so when you post your security string attempt, the server can compare your answer to the on in the session object on the server. The session is usually managed by your web browser, by cookies most often.

So my question to you is - do you maintain some session with this particular website, or is every web request detached from the previous ones?